# Can no longer save R/RStudio scripts on OneDrive - Windows

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, onedrive

R version: 4.0.3
RStudio version: 1.3
Windows 10, 1909

At my work I have to use OneDrive to store all my files and R scripts. This has worked fine up until recently. Now I get an error message when trying to save or modify an R script. I can create a new script and save it once, but if I try to make changes and save it again the error prevents me from doing so.

The error message in RStudio is:

**"The create operation failed because the name contained at least one mount point which resolves to a volume to which the specified device object is not attached"**

Not the most helpful error message.

The same behavior happens in R itself, but the error message just says it cannot save.

I have seen some talk online about this being related to that latest Windows 10 version (1909), but I started to experience the issue about 2 weeks before my computer updated to 1909. Besides, my work will not allow a roll back to the previous version.

Microsoft's OneDrive team failed to provide any help on this because they see it as an error on the R/RStudio side.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any solution?

Comment: I think the problem is on both sides. It is possible (given Microsoft's tendency to make internal changes with unknown or uncommunicated side-effects like this) that OneDrive changed something recently that now makes it harder for non-Microsoft products to do every-day tasks. Having said that ... have you tried rebooting the OS? Sad as it is, that often fixes glitches like this. (Second thought: can you edit and resave these onedrive-based files in a different non-MS editor such as notepad or notepad++?)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your response. The problem has persisted for a couple months now, so I've restarted my computer several times already. The notepad idea could work to change and save script text, but it would be pretty painful for the work that we do, which involves making a change to the R scripts and running them immediately. The error message comes up with each change, even before attempting to save it.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use notepad every time ... I'm trying to help you troubleshoot if/where the problem might be. For instance, if `notepad` cannot do it, then the problem is almost certainly with OneDrive or something in your Windows. If `notepad` can do it, then either the issue is with something weird on your computer or OneDrive tech support is correct, it's an issue with R or RStudio.

Comment: Something else you can try: `writeLines("quux", "path/to/onedrive/file.txt")`, then repeat and see if it errs. It might not be an exact replication of the conditions, but ... it's a thought.

Comment: Yeah I see. Notepad works fine. I think the error is definitely coming from R, but it seems to be related to the most recent update of Windows because it happened for my colleague as well when their PC updated. The writeLines() code does work without showing the error message I get when I try to make a change to R scripts or save them.

Comment: If `writelines` in R itself works, then it's something in the RStudio IDE, not R. That sounds like a minor distinction, but most of the IDE has very little to do with R from an execution standpoint.

Comment: For that, I suggest you are more likely to get results if you go to RStudio community forums and/or post a bug report (issue) on RStudio's github repo.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but when I try to save R scripts using R (Not RStudio) on OneDrive, they fail as well. The error message just says that it cannot save, but it started occurring at the same time as the RStudio error. Will post on RStudio regardless. Thank you