# How to solve an error saving script file in R?

Tags: r, windows-10

I can't save my scripts in R
How could I solve this problem?

[image]

On certain occasions, when I try to save a script, I come across this error shown above. It's the first time I've come across this on Win10. Never seen this on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There are a number of OneDrive questions and answers here; does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145736/can-no-longer-save-r-rstudio-scripts-on-onedrive-windows

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I'll see it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour  Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.